# Entity Framework Inheritance Code First

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, inheritance, polymorphism

I am new to EF and as per this [tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) I have set up my code-first classes to have base calls `TableA's` ID as primary and foreign key for `TableB` as below:

```
[Table("TableA")]
public abstract class TableA
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

[Table("TableB")]
public class TableB: TableA
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }        
    public int Width { get; set; }
}
```

In controller when doing a query:

```
 var a = db.TableB.ToList();
```

I get 0 for tableB IDs. But while debugging I can see the base class having the appropriate IDs. so I did a loop and inside it assigned IDs using `item.ID = ((TableA)(item)).ID;`.

The above works as in it assigns the IDs so I can see them in my view, but is this the right way to do it? Is there any other solutions?

**EDIT :** 
Here is the dbcontext:

```
public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public ProductContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<TableA> TableA { get; set; }

        public DbSet<TableB> TableB { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your DbContext?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When dealing with inheritance in the Entity Framework you should access the entities through their parent DbSet. This means that in your case, you should access your `TableB` entities trough the `TableA` property on your `DbContext`. The `TableB` property should be removed.

If you would query on `TableA`  you would get all entities that inherit from `TableA` (in your case only `TableB` entities but there could be more).
If you want to filter down to `TableB` entities you can use the `OfType` method like this:

```
from b in context.TableA.OfType<TableB>() 
select b;
```

Comment: "The TableB property should be removed." do you mean the ID should be removed from TableB as it inherits from TableA?

Comment: Yes the Id property should be removed but also the TableB property on your DbContext

Comment: +1 that works thanks. got a question if you dont mind :).. what if I had TableC that derived from TableB with its own primary ID but TableB having a foreign key to TableC do I need to specify it on TableB?

Comment: If C derives from B it won't have it's own ID. You need to share the ID in the whole hierarchy. On a side note, I would try to lose the ID of tables and foreign keys. You are working Code First. Try to think in entities and relations. Just let EF figure out the default mapping and try to adjust it when necessary

Comment: Ok thanks for explanation, can you explain what you mean by loosing the ID of tables and foreign keys. do you mean in classes just delete foreign and primary keys and the relation would be sufficient?

Comment: No I mean in the way you are thinking about your model. You are still designing in terms of a database. EF Code First allows you to focus on your classes.